# Incorrect timestamp control value

Tags: labview

After placing Timestamp control on my panel, I've changed it's properties to display only time, as I don't need date part.

Value shown on this control is, as expected, `00:00:00`, but if I press up button I get `01:00:01`, `01:00:02`, ..., or if I press down button, I get `00:59:59`, `00:59:58` and so on.
If I write `01:00:00` inside a text box of the control, it automatically switches back to `00:00:00`.
If I change timestamp value to double, I get `0` for `00:00:00`, `-1` for `00:59:59`, and `1` for `1:00:01`.

So it seems as if this control uses 01:00:00 as a base time. Inside it's properties I've found minimum value of `01:00:00,000 1600-01-01`. Changing it to `00:00:00` doesn't give expected result.

Is there any way for this control to work properly as a normal time span control ?

Comment: I was trying to duplicate your problem and I found out that if I write `00:00:00,000` manually into the control, the behaviour is corrected. I have no idea why this would happen, but you could give it a try.

Comment: Partially corrected. Pressing up button will give me 00:00:01 - great, but converted to double it still gives -3599 (-1h+1s=-3599s). Also, if you get to value of 1h, problem comes back in it's full scale (so again no 01:00:00 value on display, because it gets switched to 00:00:00).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if the behavior is correct or not, but I can explain it.

The problem is that you're using absolute time. In absolute time, LV uses the first midnight of 1904 UTC as the epoch (the zero value) and when you have that value it displays it as all zeros. Once you change it, the display goes back to normal. The reason you're seeing 1:00:00 as the base is because you're in the GMT+1 timezone and LV automatically fixes the display when the value is not zero.

What I would suggest is replacing the timestamp control with a numeric control, going to the format page in the properties and changing the control to display relative time. 
Alternatively, if you do want the time to be absolute, then set the value of the control to the correct timestamp using a local variable before starting.

Comment: I tried switching timezone, but nothing changed. Main thing, no, i don't need absolute time, but don't know how to change it in timestamp control. That is why I'll go your way, and replace it with a numeric control with relative time format. Thank you for this solution.

Comment: You can't change it in a timestamp control. A timestamp control uses absolute time by definition. That's the whole purpose of the timestamp data type.

Comment: now i know that this control does not accept format of relative time (tried a few combinations, before your answer showed up). I wrote in main question, that I need 'time span' which of course, in case of LabVIEW, means that relative time of numeric control was what I was looking for. So thanks again ^_^.